# Need help with reading this fragment from piano sheet

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, sight-reading

I'm a beginner in playing the piano and I came across these signs that I don't know. What do they mean and how should it be played?

[image: Music Fragment]

Second measure, first notes for the right hand:

- the three dots after the notes
- and the mini crossed note before them

Comment: You have to look for *music symbols*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dot after a note extends the length of the note by half. In this case, the eighth notes are extended the length of 3 sixteenth notes. There's a sharp sign before the dotted eighth on G which means to play a G# (half step above the G.) The note with a slash is a grace note. Depending on the style, a grace note is played just before the main note or "crushed" at the same time (played quickly and released while the main note is held.)

Comment: 'A dot after a note extends the length of the note by half'. Talking of a one beat note,(crotchet, quarter note),  that's always true! A dotted one beat note is extended by half, becoming one-and-a-half beats long. Reason for picking up on this is a dot *increases a note's value by half of its own value*. Lots of newbies get confuse by this!